# List of Successors of successors in a DiGraph in Networkx

Tags: python, networkx, digraphs, jsnetworkx

I'm working on a function that creates a family tree using a directed graph in networkx, where the nodes are family members with the date of birth as a node attribute.
Now what i want to do is to make another function that given the graph G and a name of a node, returns a sorted list of all the "grandsons" of that node. So basically, i do this:

```
return sort(G.successors(G.successors(node)))
```

But since `G.successors` returns a list of the successors, this doesn't work.

How would you approach this?

Thanks!

Comment: There is a networkx method called `nx.descendants(g, source)` which "Return all nodes reachable from \(source\) in G."

Answer (score 1):

You can write your own function for this task. If you are sure your `DiGraph` is a tree, you can replace the `set()` with a `list`. Please also add a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with the desired output in your next questions.

```
import networkx as nx

family_tree = nx.DiGraph()

family_tree.add_edges_from([("GP", "P1"), ("GP", "P2"), ("P1", "S1"), ("S1", "GS1"), ("P1", "S2")])

def successors_of_successors(graph, node):
    results = set()
    for successor in graph.successors(node):
        results.update(graph.successors(successor))

    return results

print(successors_of_successors(family_tree, "GP"))
# {'S2', 'S1'}
print(successors_of_successors(family_tree, "P1"))
# {'GS1'}
```

Comment: Thanks, you can simply accept the answer ;) This saves comment space, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers